# Sending key presses in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to simulate right arrow key press from HW keyboard on iOS programmatically, something similar to the CGEventRef/CGEventPost used for OS X. Unfortunately these are not supported on iOS.

Any advice will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborate it. What do you mean by simulating key press from keyboard? Do you want to create a `UIButton` to do something

Comment: No, I need to capture spacebar press on the HW keyboard and convert it to right arrow press. I'm capturing spacebar press with: 'keyCommands' but I didn't find a way to simulate a right arrow key press. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, my original problem is that when my app uses Japanese keyboard, typing any character displays a candidate bar with replacement suggestions. If I use it with some standard iOS app, e.g. Notes, hitting spacebar or right arrow on the Bluetooth keyboard selects the next suggestion on the candidate bar.  For some reason (I hasn't been able to find out why), in my app, the right arrow works as expected, but the spacebar doesn't select the next suggestion; instead, it just types a space. Would be really helpful if I could understand why. Thanks!